# NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_block'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd

Apparently this method exists and I've been trying to use it, but it doesn't seem to work in my use case.

```
test "should get appropriate autocomplete results upon ideal request" do
  get :index, { "term" => "al", "max_results" => "20"}

  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:payers)

  assert json_response.length <= 20

  assert_block do 
    json_response.each do |payer_hash|
      return false unless payer_hash['label'][0..1] == "al"
    end

    true
  end
end
```

That is the test. At first I thought I was using it wrong because I have a block inside of it. But, at the same time, if what I had inside was a simple one-liner, I could just use assert. Am I using it wrong? Is it deprecated in Rails 4.1? If so, what is the new way to do this?